# Create a string from a specific key/value in an array

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an array collection that I want to pull values out of to create a string. I am using lodash to help out with the loop.

```
var arr = [
  {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Lorem"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "ipsum"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "dolor"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "sit"
  }
];

_.forEach(arr, function(value) {
  var jawn = value.name;
  jawn.join('\n');
  console.log(jawn);
});
```

What I want to do is

```
jawn.join('\n');
```

So the result for `console.log(jawn);` would be...

```
"Lorem
ipsum
dolor
sit
amet"
```

I know this but I'm drawing a blank for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with lodash, but you can easily achieve the desired result using `Array#map`. I bet it would be pretty similar with lodash.

```js
var arr = [ { "id": 0, "name": "Lorem" }, { "id": 1, "name": "ipsum" }, { "id": 3, "name": "dolor" }, { "id": 4, "name": "sit" } ],
    res = arr.map(v => v.name).join('\n');
    console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Without lodash:

```
arr.map(function(value) {
  return value.name;
}).join('\n');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could map only the name and join the array with `\n`.

```js
var arr = [{ id: 0, name: "Lorem" }, { id: 1, name: "ipsum" }, { id: 3, name: "dolor" }, { id: 4, name: "sit" }],
    result = arr.map(a => a.name).join('\n');

console.log(result);
```